# How to return passed present items in an array of javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function and I want to return true if the passed item is present in all the arrays inside arrayOfArrays# check if it appears across all arrays.

```
function item(allArrays, item) {


}

Run against this code
  describe('item', () => {
    it('returns true if the passed value is present in all the arrays inside the passed array', () => {
      const allArrays= [
        [9, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 9],
        [-2, 9, -1],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
      ];
      expect(item(allArrays, 9)).to.be.true;
    });
it('returns false if the passed value is not present in at least one array inside the passed array', () => {
  let allArrays= [[9, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9], [-2, 1, -1]];
  expect(item(allArrays, 9)).to.be.false;
  allArrays= [[6, 2, 3], [4, 5, 8], [-2, 9, -1]];
  expect(item(allArrays, 9)).to.be.false;
  allArrays= [[4, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9], [-2, 9, -1]];
  expect(item(allArrays, 9)).to.be.false;
});
```

});

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give us more context? Are there particular aspects of using arrays that you don't understand, or have you run into any error messages in your attempts to write it?

Comment: return true if the passed item is present in all the arrays inside allArrays
  check if it appears accross all arrays

Comment: [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) can be useful to make an implementation for what you need.

Comment: @Mick I see. Because you've listed the problem without a lot of research effort or documented attempts, this question may be interpreted as a [low-effort or zero-effort question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions), as StackOverflow attracts a lot of homework and coding-quiz questions that the community generally dislikes. Note that strongly negative questions may result in a question ban, which may impact your ability to ask better questions in the future. Good luck with the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let isCommon = (arrays, v) =>
  arrays.every(a => a.includes(v));
  
const allArrays = [
  [9, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 9],
  [-2, 9, -1],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
];
console.log(isCommon(allArrays, 5)); // false
console.log(isCommon(allArrays, 9)); // true
```